# How does this C++ parser work?

Tags: c++, parsing, grammar

I am currently reading "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup and I'm having problems understanding how this particular grammar is implemented.

Here is the grammar and its rules:

```
Expression:
    Term
    Expression "+" Term
    Expression "-" Term
Term:
    Primary
    Term "*" Primary
    Term "/" Primary
    Term "%" Primary
Primary:
    Number
    "(" Expression ")"
Number:
    floating-point literal
```

However, this is how Term is implemented:

```
double term()
{
    double left = primary();
    Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream

    while(true) {
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '*':
            left *= primary();
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        case '/':
        {
            double d = primary();
            if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
            left /= d;
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        }
        default:
            ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
            return left;
    }
    }
}
```

Why do we, in the switch statement, call `left *= primary();` if the token is equal to "*", instead of `left *= term()`?

I have tried to replace `left *= primary();` with `left *= term()` (did the same thing for division) and the program still worked fine. However, I don't understand the design decision Bjarne had in mind, that is, why he implemented the function the way he did. Maybe I am missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a 'C++ grammar'. This is a parser implemented in C++.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: This has nothing to do with order of evaluation. [It is important not to confuse evaluation order for precedence.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/300808/17853)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do we, in the switch statement, call `left *= primary();` if the token is equal to `"*"`, instead of `left *= term()?`

Because the grammar says:

```
Term:
    Primary
    Term "*" Primary
    Term "/" Primary
    Term "%" Primary
```

Note that if C++ (and C) had an exponentiation operator, or his sample grammar had unary operators, what you would have seen is the more usual:

```
Expression:
    Term
    Expression "+" Term
    Expression "-" Term
Term:
    Factor
    Term "*" Factor
    Term "/" Factor
    Term "%" Factor
Factor:
    Primary
    Primary "**" Factor /* note right-associativity */
Primary:
    "+" Primary
    "-" Primary
    Number
    "(" Expression ")"
Number:
    floating-point literal
```

Comment: That grammar allows "+ - + - + - + 5".  I think you need `"+" Number` (and similarly for minus.

Comment: @MartinBonner Correct. It's deliberate. `-(-(-5))` is legal C for example. Your suggestion would make it illegal.

Comment: Oh I see.  Unary plus is not legal on generalized expressions though:  `+( +(+5))` is not legal, and as I said `- - 5` is also not legal.  Conclusion: The grammar is a bit more complex!

Comment: @MartinBonner It certainly is. What I have written above is mathematically correct. C may not support unary + at all, and repeated unary minuses may be illegal in C for heuristic reasons such as avoiding confusion with pre-decrement.

Comment: @EJP Just to check my understanding - let's say I have 2*3. First `primary()` gets called and gets 2. Then, a token is read and it is `*`. Since it is `*`, it gets the following `Primary` by calling `primary()` again. However, since `Term` is also a `Primary` (1st rule in the grammar I stated above), the first `Primary` I fetched is no longer treated as a  `Primary`, but is now treated as a `Term` and the whole expression is treated as `Term "*" Primary`, that is, a `Term` (because `Term` is defined as `Term "*" Primary`). Am I correct?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I know that the whole thing is a `Term`, however, in the above comment I was trying to step through the code, line by line, to try to emulate what the program does (ommiting stuff such as "The program starts from `main()`, then `main()` calls `expression()` etc.)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Ah, so my explanation is correct, I was just looking at it the wrong way. I should tread the `Term` as a combination of `Primary`s, rather than the variable changing its meaning... Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You should just look at the target symbol of the production as a return value, and the non-terminal symbols in the rules as functions to be evaluated, that return intermediate values. Which, in the code you posted, is exactly what they are.

Comment: @EJP I don't think I quite understand what you said in your last comment.

Answer (score -1):

Because the production is not `Term "*" Term`.

It is `Term "*" Primary`.

The reason for this in the grammar itself is so that if you have any nested `Term`s in the expression then they are forced to "appear" on the left-hand side from a parsing perspective. The right-hand side is effectively persuaded to only contain primary expressions (which do not contain other operators). When this is applied to recursively parsing your "program", the result is that the operators are left-associative, resulting in `((a*b)*c)`, rather than `(a*(b*c))`.

Such a grammar will only go "downwards", not "upwards", otherwise you end up in a big mess of ambiguity or, at the very least, an unnatural associativity that confuses people trying to write arithmetic in your language.

Of course, for multiplication, the arithmetic result is notionally the same regardless. When you start using different operators, though, the problem becomes clear: `((a*b)/c)` is not the same as `(a/(b*c))`.

Comment: The fact that `primary` doesn't contain other operators is irrelevant. What is relevant that that is it higher in precedence than the non-terminal symbol the rule it appears in is part of. Consider `Expression: Term "+" Term` for example.

Comment: @EJP: The fact that `Primary` doesn't contain other operators is how that difference in precedence comes about, no? Grammar productions don't have precedence; operators do. The fact is that `*` is made left-associative by the grammar not allowing another `*` on the RHS of a `Term` (by virtue of only allowing a `Primary` and by a `Primary` not having a production that utters `*`).

Comment: No. The operator precedence is firmly embedded in this grammar, without any further notations being required. [You haven't considered `Expression: Term "+" Term` as I suggested. It is an example of a subordinate non-terminal which does contain operators.]

Comment: @EJP: I did consider it, and I rejected it, as explained above.

Comment: You haven't explained anything. You've only asserted. The production I cited is a counter-example to your assertion.

Comment: @EJP: I explained in the answer and in the comment. Let's agree to disagree because I'm not in the mood for a debate in this hostile form.

Comment: You can disagree all you want, but the grammar already contains the operator precedence, and the fact that the subordinate non-terminal doesn't contain operators remains 100% irrelevant. No two ways about it. Consider the obvious extension to logical-expressions. Subordinate non-terminals with operators everywhere. You don't appear to understand how these things actually work.

Comment: And you can't just 'reject' the production I cited. It is still sitting there, as a counter-example to your theory.